# partitions that contain two singleton blocks one and n.

Tags: combinatorics

How many partitions [n] contain at least one of the singleton blocks 1 and n? I am having trouble doing this problem using the Sieve formula. Is it possible? and if so how do i go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use inclusion-exclusion on this one. Your answer is equal to:

The number of partitions containing the singleton 1
$+$ The number of partitions containing the singleton n
$-$ The number of partitions containing both singletons.

Now, a partition containing the singleton 1 is just any partition of the $n-1$ other numbers, plus the singleton 1, so the number of partitions needed for the first line is the same as the total number of partitions of $n-1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: i see the logic being used so the number of partitions containing singleton 1 would be S(n-1,k), and the number of partitions containing the singleton n would be S(n+1,k) correct?

Comment: I am also a bit confused about what the intersection would look like in terms of stirling numbers of the second kind.